# how to scan a grid and sum the number of filled spaces in the grid row by row and add them up individually

Tags: java

//this is what I'm up to so far, this 2d array doesn't make sense even one bit. appreciate the //help

```
    public static int[] rowCounts(Aquarium p)
{
    // TODO 16
    int []rowCounts=new int[p.getSize()];

    for (int i=0;i<p.getSize() ;i++){
        for (int j=0; j< )
        if (Spaces[i] == Space.WATER){

        }
    }

    return rowCounts;
}
```

//my next question after this would be how to do the same but this time only for columns

Comment: What is `Space`? Your code seems overly complex. Start simplifying by giving your variables meaningful names, rather than nums, sums and counts; what's the difference!?

Comment: I wasn't sure what spaces were myself but Space.WATER is an enum class defined somewhere else in the code. I didn't know how to define the Spaces variable, this is a java code for a game called aquarium puzzle, space is a square of some size in the grid. and once again really appreciate the help

Comment: You've changed your code considerably, but I'm still unclear of the problem. Could you describe exactly what your array is and what kind of sum you are after? And where is the 2d array?

Comment: yes so the array is a 2d array of spaces. at any time, they can be either filled with air, filled with water or not filled. the purpose of the assignment is to find the sum of each row of spaces that are filled with water and then for each row put the number in a single int digit and in a spikey bracket like if sum of row 0 and row 1 are 12 and 4 respectively the code output would have to be {12,4}

Comment: Ok.  So, I presume `Aquarium p` has a width and a depth of `spaces`.  What does `p.getSize()` return?  Is it the width or depth (number of rows or number of columns)?  You need these details separately so that you can iterate over the `spaces` in either direction.  Does `p` also contain the 2d array of `spaces`, and if so do you need to extract this array from `p` before iterating over these elements?